# Is it possible to use Flow with Room delete or insert operations as it's used in RxJava with Single or Maybe that returns row ids?

Tags: android, android-room, kotlin-flow

Calling

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insert(entity: PostEntity): Flow<Long>
   
@Delete
fun deletePost(entity: PostEntity): Flow<Long>
```

returns compile error

```
 Not sure how to handle insert method's return type.
    public abstract kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow<java.util.List<java.lang.Long>> insertFlow(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

Isn't possible to use Flow with Int or long to get ids for results of database operations like in RxJava?

```
@Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
fun insert(entity: T): Maybe<Long>

@Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
fun insert(entity: T): Single<Long>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [Async queries with Kotlin coroutines in Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#kotlin-coroutines), the equivalent for `Maybe` and `Single` in Kotlin coroutines is `suspend`:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insert(entity: PostEntity): Long

@Delete
suspend fun deletePost(entity: PostEntity): Long
```

Comment: I hope in next updates there would be support for flow like `Maybe` and `Single`, i guess i should use `flow{emit(dao.delete)}` for now.

Comment: That makes no sense for single operations like inserts and delete - a suspending function is exactly what you should be using in coroutines for one off operations.

Comment: What about operations that need to chained like in RxJava. For  instance check what to do after delete or insert operation such as dao.delete().flatMap{id-> doSomething}...

Comment: In coroutines, you just put that code after the suspending method call. It looks like sequential, normal code, but each suspending method runs asynchronously, resuming only when it is done. That's the [basic idea behind coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html).

Comment: The android.developer **doc guide** about **async dao operation** is moved, from the page linked in the answer, to this dedicated page: [Write asynchronous DAO queries](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/async-queries). It contains a synoptic table on the topic of this thread.

Comment: @Thracian can you please expand on your comment of using flow{emit(dao.delete)}? -ianhanniballake can you give an example on how to chain the operations after observing room database via suspend? There seems to be an implicit answer here but it's not clear.